# Creating a cookie using jquery to store name/value pairs of information

Tags: jquery, cookies

I need to store a cookie that has the following information:

key1: datetime
key2: datetime
key3: datetime

How can i create and access the cookie with the above properties?

I need to manipulate this cookie via javascript (I am using jquery).

(side question, javascript cookie work is 'live' correct? i.e. it doesn't need a postback to change cookie values etc?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- You don't need jQuery to read/write cookies.  You can use plain javascript.  Some good examples are here:
  http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html
- You can use this jQuery plugin to make getting and setting cookies a little easier:

  http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie
- And yes, read/writing cookies is a live action as you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

1. [jQuery Cookies plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie) makes life easy.
2. Cookies live on the client's computer, not the server. There is no need to postback when manipulating cookies.